# Access the array Object property value through for loop

Tags: javascript

I want access the object property which in inside array how to access that through a for loop ex:

```
arr[{A:1},{A:2},{B:3},{C:3}]
```

i want sum of each object.

Comment: What you have tried so far ? please post your code also

Comment: Tip: while iterating over the array, use `Object.values()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have same known key in object, then you can try this

```
var data = [{a:6},{a:8},{a:9}];
var dataLength = data.length;
var total = 0;
var i = 0;

while(i < dataLength){
total += data[i]["a"];
i++;
}
```

If you have object with unkown keys / dynamic keys, then use this,

```
var data = [{a:6},{b:8},{c:9,e:5}];
var dataLength = data.length;
var total = 0;
var i = 0;

while(i < dataLength){

for(var propName in data) {
    if(data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) {
        var propValue = data[propName];
        total += propValue;
    }
}

i++;
}
```

Comment: His input has different object keys.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [{A:1},{A:2},{B:3},{C:3}] 

let sum = arr.reduce((ac, o) => ac + Object.values(o)[0], 0);

console.log(sum);
```